# Put php into onchange <select>

Tags: php, html, select, onchange

Can I put php code into `<select onchange="php-code">` to call server script, or maybe another way to call it, when select tag changes?

Comment: Gotta love those, eh? @khandelwaldeval

Comment: `onchange` is client side and php is serverside. You can use AJAX to request the server

Comment: You can call a Javascript function on the <select onchange>, and the function may submit a form to execute PHP code.